# $l_2(S)$is a hilbert space where S is a subset

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

> Let S be a non-empty set and $l_2(S)$ be the set of all complex functions $f$ defined on $S$ with the following two properties:
>
> $(1) \{s:f(s)\ne0\}$ is empty or countable. $(2) \sum{|f(s)|}^2 < +\infty$
>
> Then show that :
>
> (a) $l_2(S)$ forms a complex linear space with respect to pointwise addition and scalar multiplication.
>
> (b) If norm and inner product is defined as, $||f||=(\sum{|f(s)|}^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and  $ <f,g>=\sum f(s)\bar{g(s)}$ respectively, then $l_2(S)$ is actually a Hilbert space.

My attempt :

(a) Easily done.

(b) Clearly a complex linear space and then assuming it to be Banach, considering  for each $f \in l_2(S)$ , the form $f(s)=f_1(s)+if_2(s)$ i.e. considering its  Real and Imaginary parts, computed and proved that the 'parallelogram law' holds for $l_2(S)$. But stuck on how to show that the space is actually complete.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Actually, $\ell^p(S)$ is complete for all $1\leq p\leq\infty$ and any set $S$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486786/proving-the-l-p-space-is-complete for example.

Comment: Besides if You are interested in the analogous case of $p$-Schatten classes You might have a look at Theorem 15 here:https://www.fernuni-hagen.de/analysis/download/diplomarbeit_melech.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce  to the case that $l_2$ is complete:

Assume you have a cauchy sequence $(f_n)$ in $l_2(S)$. Set $$N=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N} } \{s:f_n(s)\neq 0\}.$$ Then you  identify $l_2(N)$ as a subspace of $l_2(S)$  and under this identification your sequence lives in $l_2(N)$. As $N$ is countable  $l_2(N)\cong l_2$ or $l_2(N)\cong \mathbb{C}^N$ depending on whether $N$ is infinite or not,  so your sequence converges.

A proof for the completeness of $l_2$ can be found here (just replace $\mathbb R$ by $\mathbb C$): [Understanding the proof of $l_2$ being complete.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2492346/572257)